# Is there a way to compare current project with a git branch and create a patch of the differences

Tags: git, intellij-idea, patch

In IntelliJ I can right click on a folder or the root of the project and do a 'Compare with branch..." under the Git context menu. I'd like to get the results of that diff into a patch/diff file. How can I accomplish this either from IntelliJ or command line git?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `diff` option you searched for is `-p` ([doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#git-diff---patch)).

```
git diff -p reference-branch target-branch > yourfile.patch
```

seems the simplest way to achieve this at any time.

---

However you could also use the fact that the current branch is assumed as the reference if you only give one commit reference for the command.

So, with your `reference-branch` currently checked-out :

```
git diff -p target-branch > yourfile.patch
```